# How to test an alternate configuration with exim4?

Tags: debian, exim

I have a working exim4 setup using the split configuration mode, to which I'd like to make some changes.

Obviously, just meddling around with the live system is not very desireable, and I have no test system available, so I'd like to make a copy of the configuration files, and test changes to this copy using the exim4 debug commands like -bV, -bt, etc.
Is there a parameter to force exim4 to use a different configuration directory for this test? The -C option seems to only work on single files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debian exim4 split mail configurations files in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/` are merged using the tool `update-exim4.conf`.  The default location for the merged configuration file is `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`.

Which has this help.

```
# update-exim4.conf --help
/usr/sbin/update-exim4.conf - Generate exim4 configuration files
       Options:
       ...
       -o|--output file - write output to file instead of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
       -d|--confdir directory - read input from given directory instead of /etc/exim4
```

I haven't tested, but I believe this means you could replicate /etc/exim4 to some other folder and then use a command like this `update-exim4.conf -d /path_to_config_folder/ -o /path_to_test_config_file` to generated a merged configuration file which you can then pass to exim using the -C option.

Or you can just copy the `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated` file to somewhere else, make and test your changes to the merged configuration, and then replicate those changes back to the files in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/`.

Comment: BTW, be careful with -C and -D on Debian if you haven't updated.  Apparently, in certain configurations this can cause.  http://www.debian.org/security/2011/dsa-2154